# Prove that $\max(||f||_{\infty},||f'||_{\infty})\leq \frac12 \|f'\|_{L^2([0,1])}$

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces

i want to prove this: 
$$\max\left(||f||_{\infty},||f'||_{\infty}\right)\leq \frac12 \|f'\|_{L^2([0,1])}$$
where $f\in C^1([0,1])$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

What I did is: (using Cauchy Schwartz inequality)
$$
|f(t)|=\left|\int_0^t f'(t) \,dt\right|\le \int_0^t |f'(t)| \,dt\leq \left(\int_0^1 |f'(t)|^2 \,dt\right)^{\frac12}=\|f'\|_{L^2([0,1])}$$

I don't know how to continue. Any help please?

Comment: Search "Poincare inequality" - it might help

Comment: @ZacharySelk I don't know how to find $\frac12$

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, but you didn't use $f(1) = 0$.

For $t \in [0,1]$ we have
\begin{align}
|f(t)| &= \frac12 \left|\int_0^t f'(t)\,dt\right| + \frac12\left|\int_t^1 f'(t)\,dt\right| \\
&\leq \frac12 \int_0^t |f'(t)|\,dt + \frac12\int_t^1 |f'(t)|\,dt\\
&= \frac12 \int_0^1 |f'(t)|\,dt \\
&\le 
 \frac12\left(\int_0^1 |f'(t)|^2 \,dt\right)^{\frac12}\\
&=\frac12\|f'\|_{L^2([0,1])}
\end{align}
again using Cauchy-Schwartz. Therefore $\|f\|_\infty \le \frac12\|f'\|_{L^2([0,1])}$.

The inequality $\|f'\|_\infty \le \frac12\|f'\|_{L^2([0,1])}$ isn't true.

As suggested by @Martin R, consider $f(x) = x(1-x)$. We have $\|f'\|_\infty = 1$ but $\frac12\|f'\|_{L^2([0,1])} = \frac1{2\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, your first part gives an estimate for $\|f\|_\infty$, not for $\|f'\|_\infty $. That is a part of the intended inequality, but $\|f'\|_\infty \le \frac12\|f'\|_{L^2([0,1])}$ remains to show. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @MartinR You're right, corrected. I'm not yet sure how to prove the other inequality.

Comment: Actually the estimate for $f'$ seems to be wrong, $f(x) = x(1-x)$ looks like a counter-example to me.

Comment: @MartinR in fact it can't hold with any constant other than $\frac 12$ either.

Comment: @MartinR Are you sure? We have $\|f\|_\infty = \frac14$ and $\frac12\|f'\|_{L^2([0,1])} = \frac1{2\sqrt{3}} = 0.288675...$

Comment: @mechanodroid: But  $\|f'\|_\infty = 1$.

Comment: @MartinR Whoops, yeah. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the inequality holds. For example, let $f(t)=\sin(2\pi t)$. Then 
$$ f\in C^1[0,1], f(0)=f(1)=0. $$
Clearly
$$ \max_{t\in[0,1]}|f'(t)|=2\pi,\|f'\|_{L^2[0,1]}=\sqrt2\pi. $$
But
$$ \max_{t\in[0,1]}|f'(t)|>\frac12\|f'\|_{L^2[0,1]}. $$

Comment: For extra credit you can try to show $\max |f'| \le M \|f'\|_2$ fails in general for any positive $M$.

Comment: @UmbertoP., you're right.